# Angle bisector of a Triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

Question: How can i extend the angle bisecor line in the form of ray? and how to get point of intersection with line segment BC?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(2,4){A}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){C}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](C){$C$}

\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawBisector[color=blue](B,A,C)

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use this: [Orthogonal line in tkz-euclide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368337/124842), so use `\tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through A](B,C)     
  \tkzGetPoint{X_1}

  \tkzInterLL(C,B)(A,X_1)
  \tkzGetPoint{C_1}`. C_1=intersection point.  With `\tkzDrawPoints(C_1)\tkzLabelPoints(C_1,X_1)` you can draw and label this point.

Answer (score 12):

For comparison here is an effort in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) showing Knuth's useful `whatever` notation and the declarative equation style.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    % define a distance unit
    numeric u; u = 1cm;

    % define the arbitrary points
    pair A, B, C;
    A = (3,4) scaled u;
    B = origin;
    C = (4,-2) scaled u;

    % find the angle bisector point
    z1 = whatever[B,C] = whatever * right shifted A rotatedabout(A, 1/2 (angle (C-A) + angle (B-A)));

    % find another point somewhere along the bisector ray...
    z2 = whatever[A,z1]; 
    y2 = ypart C;  % arbitrarily set the y-coordinate of z2 to the same as point C

    % now draw some of these things...
    drawarrow A -- z2 withcolor 2/3 blue;
    draw A--B--C--cycle;
    fill fullcircle scaled dotlabeldiam shifted z1 withcolor red;
    draw fullcircle scaled dotlabeldiam shifted z1;

    % and add the labels
    label.top("$A$", A);
    label.lft("$B$", B);
    label.lrt("$C$", C);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

It might help to unpick the angle bisector line:

```
z1 = whatever[B,C] = whatever * right shifted A rotatedabout(A, 1/2 (angle (C-A) + angle (B-A)));
```

The first part

```
 z1 = whatever[B,C]
```

says "define a point z1 somewhere along the line B--C".  If you tried drawing something involving `z1` at this point you would get an error saying that `z1` was an unknown pair.  So to pin it down you need to add a second element to the equation.

```
  z1 = whatever[B,C] = whatever * right;
```

This defines `z1` to be the intersection between the line B--C and a horizontal line through the origin (because  `right` is defined as the vector `(1,0)`).  Not quite what you want yet...

```
z1 = whatever[B,C] = whatever * right shifted A;
```

This defines `z1` to be the intersection of the line B--C and a horizontal line through the point `A` which is closer to what you want.  Finally:

```
z1 = whatever[B,C] = whatever * right shifted A 
                     rotatedabout(A, 1/2 (angle (C-A) + angle (B-A)));
```

defines `z1` to be the intersection of the line B--C with a line through `A` that has been rotated around `A` to the mean of the angles of the lines C--A and B--A.
This is what you need to get the bisector point.

Answer (score 2):

**1. How to get point** (*called C_1*) **of intersection with line segment BC?**
 (This (first) part is (morealess) a duplicat to [Orthogonal line in tkz-euclide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368337/124842).)

You can define a orthogonal line on BC across A with `\tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through A](B,C)`. The second point on the line could be defined with `\tkzGetPoint{}` and a arbitrary name for example `X_1` => `\tkzGetPoint{X_1}`.

The intersection point could be defined with `\tkzInterLL( )( )` and a arbitrary name for example `C_1` => `\tkzGetPoint{C_1}`. So with `\tkzInterLL(C,B)(A,X_1)` you can compute the intersection of the two lines CB and AX_1. With `\tkzGetPoint{C_1}` you get the intersection point, saved as `C_1`.

For drawing and labeling the points (Point1,Point2,Point3) you can use `\tkzLabelPoints(Point1,Point2,Point3)`,... and `\tkzDrawPoints(Point1,Point2,Point3)`.

**EDIT:**

**2. How to extend the angle bisecor line in the form of ray?**

With `\tkzDrawLine[add = 0 and 0.1,color=green](A,tkzPointResult)` you can draw a line from `A` to the last `tkzPointResult`, which is (here) at the end `C_1`. To extends the line add some space with `add = AddStart and AddEnd` (to extends start or ending point) => `\tkzDrawLine[add = 0 and 0.1,color=green](A,tkzPointResult)`

See manuanl capter [7.5.1 Utilisation de \tkzInCenter avec trois points](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/tkz-euclide-screen.pdf) on page 30.

**3. Arrow tip:**

If you like an arrow tip you can use: `arrows=-triangle 60` or other [Triangular Arrow Tips](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120805/124842)

`\tkzDrawLine[add = 0 and 0.1,color=green,arrows=-triangle 60](A,tkzPointResult)`

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzDefPoint(2,4){A}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){C}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](A){$A$}
\tkzLabelPoint[left](B){$B$}
\tkzLabelPoint[right](C){$C$}

\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawBisector[color=blue](B,A,C)

  \tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through A](B,C)   

  \tkzGetPoint{X_1}

  %\tkzLabelPoints(X_1)\tkzDrawPoints(X_1)

  \tkzInterLL(C,B)(A,X_1)
  \tkzGetPoint{C_1}

  %\tkzDrawLine[add = 0 and 0.1,color=green](A,tkzPointResult) 
  \tkzDrawLine[add = 0 and 0.1,color=green,arrows=-triangle 60](A,tkzPointResult) 
  \tkzDrawLine[add = 0.3 and 0.1,color=orange](B,tkzPointResult)

  \tkzDrawPoints(C_1)\tkzLabelPoints(C_1)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks and how to extend that bisector AC1? in the form of ray

Comment: Great thanks for your beautiful explanation..........

Comment: You can use `\tkzDrawLine[add = 0 and 0.1,color=green](A,tkzPointResult)`, see answer update.